# in hibernate4.1.9 buildsessionfactory method is deprecated so why serviceRegistry is paased to buildsessionFactory

Tags: java

in hibernate4.1.9 buildsessionfactory method is deprecated so why serviceRegistry is passed to buildsessionFactory

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
public class Util {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct sir.So i just dont get the thing that why serviceRegistry is passed in buildSessionFactory method.